# cordova-plugin-media-with-compression on iOS can't seem to play audio files after moving

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, cordova-plugins

I am using cordova-plugin-media-with-compression in an Ionic 2 app.

On iOS I can record and playback if I pass `startRecord()` a filename and call that again without changing `this.media`.

I can't seem to play audio files stored elsewhere in the file system - as I have to pass a new src to `startRecord()` and this is the bit I think I am doing incorrectly.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ModalController, LoadingController, ToastController, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { File, FileEntry, Entry, FileError, DirectoryEntry} from 'ionic-native';

declare var Media: any; // stops errors w/ cordova-plugin-media-with-compression types

@Component({
  selector: 'page-add-doc',
  templateUrl: 'add-doc.html'
})
export class AddDocPage {
  isRecording = false;
  isRecorded = false;
  audioUrl ='';
  localAudioUrl = '';
  media: any;
  newFileName: string;
  newFileNameM4A: string;
  homerAudio = 'http://techslides.com/demos/samples/sample.m4a'

  constructor(private modalCtrl: ModalController,
              private loadingCtrl: LoadingController,
              private toastCtrl: ToastController,
              private platform: Platform,
            ) {
              platform.ready()
                .then(() => {
                  console.log('Platform Ready');
                });
              }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
      this.newFileName = new Date().getTime().toString();
      this.newFileNameM4A = this.newFileName +'.m4a';
  }

  onRecordAudio() {
    this.media = new Media(this.newFileNameM4A);
    this.media.startRecord();
    this.isRecording = true;
  }
  onStopRecordAudio() {
    this.media.stopRecord();
    this.media.release();
    this.isRecording = false;
    this.isRecorded = true;
    try {
      File.copyFile(File.tempDirectory, this.newFileNameM4A, File.dataDirectory, this.newFileNameM4A)
        .then(
            (data: Entry) => {
              this.audioUrl = data.nativeURL;
        });
    } catch (FileError) {
      console.log(FileError)
    };
  }

  onPlayback() {
    this.media = new Media(this.newFileNameM4A);
    this.media.play();
    this.media.release();
  }
  onPlaybackTempDirectory() {
    this.media = new Media(File.tempDirectory + this.newFileNameM4A);
    this.media.play();
    this.media.release();
  }

  onPlaybackDataDirectory() {
    this.media = new Media(File.dataDirectory + this.localAudioUrl);
    this.media.play();
    this.media.release();
  }    

  onHomerAudio() {
    this.media = new Media(this.homerAudio)
    this.media.play();
    this.media.release();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Believe I may have solved this with the answer from https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-7007

Comment: I cannot run `onHomerAudio()` method also on android device? can you tell me how to do that?